# Simple question... Can you display the latest revision author?

Tags: ee2, author, edit-date

I need to track revisions for some docs and I am displaying the original creation author and date via:

```
<li>Created: {entry_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}</li>
<li>Author: {author}</li>
```

I need to display the latest edit date and author too. I am pretty certain this would be something like:

```
<li>Last Edit: {edit_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}</li>
<li>Author: {author}</li>
```

I just don't know of a last editing/revision author tag.

Is that available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any tag available for entry revision. You can do it with following code example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL NAME" ...........}

    <li>Created: {entry_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}</li>
    <li>Author: {author}</li>

    {exp:query sql="SELECT exp_members.screen_name AS revision_author, exp_entry_versioning.version_date FROM exp_entry_versioning JOIN exp_members ON exp_entry_versioning.author_id=exp_members.member_id WHERE entry_id='{entry_id}' ORDER BY version_date DESC LIMIT 1"}

        <li>Last Edit: {version_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}</li>
        <li>Author: {revision_author}</li>

    {/exp:query}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhashkar. I just didn't want to write an extra query if there wasn't a need. This works swell.

Comment: I developed a plugin for it. One can download it from here: http://www.sidd3.com/entry-revisions-plugin/. Hope, it would be useful.

Comment: Nice. I'll take a look at it when I get the chance.